# Akka Streams GraphStage

Tags: java, scala, akka-stream

Using `GraphStage` is recommended in Akka Streams, but I could not find any documentation on using the `getStageActor()` method in Java (all of the documentation that I have found used Scala).

How can I convert the following code to Java?

```
lazy val self: StageActor = getStageActor(onMessage)
```

and

```
private def onMessage(x: (ActorRef, Any)): Unit =
{
  x match {
    case (_, msg: String) =>
      log.info("received msg, queueing: {} ", msg)
      messages = messages.enqueue(msg)
      pump()
  }
}
```

Comment: What documentation links have you tried? All documentation is mirrored between java and Scala apis.

Comment: @Konrad'ktoso'Malawski   Actually I checked all of the documentations for akka, but unfortunately I could not find anything useful.

Comment: @Konrad'ktoso'Malawski
what I want to do is to emit data later after defining a source to Kafka. 
by help of ActorPublisher it seems it is possible, but it is recommended not to use it, instead we must use GraphStage. Do you know any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`getStageActor` method documentation](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/stage/GraphStageLogic.html#getStageActor-scala.Function1-), it accepts a value of type

```
scala.Function1<scala.Tuple2<ActorRef,java.lang.Object>, scala.runtime.BoxedUnit>
```

which in Scala looks like

```
((ActorRef, AnyRef)) => Unit
```

In Java this type would be semantically equivalent (using the [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) interface) to

```
Function<Tuple<ActorRef, Object>, Void>
```

where `Tuple<A, B>` is a class which contains two values of types `A` and `B`.

Therefore, to call the `getStageActor` method, you need to create a value of the aforementioned type. You can do it directly by constructing an instance of a class extending `AbstractFunction1`:

```
import scala.Function1;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;
import scala.runtime.BoxedUnit;

getStateActor(new AbstractFunction1<Tuple2<ActorRef, Object>, BoxedUnit>() {
    @Override
    public BoxedUnit apply(Tuple2<ActorRef, Object> args) {
        return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
    }
});
```

If you use Java 8, there are syntactically nicer ways to do it using lambda expressions.

If you use Scala 2.12+, then `scala.Function1` is a functional interface, and you can use lambda expressions directly:

```
getStateActor((args: Tuple2<ActorRef, Object>) -> BoxedUnit.UNIT);
```

If you use an older version of Scala, then due to the way traits are compiled, `Function1` is not a functional interface, and you will need to use the [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) library. With it, the code looks like

```
import static scala.compat.java8.JFunction.*;

getStateActor(func((args: Tuple2<ActorRef, Object>) -> BoxedUnit.UNIT));
```

Then, to implement the logic of the function, you can access elements of the tuple using the `_1()` and `_2()` methods:

```
(args: Tuple2<ActorRef, Object>) -> {
    Object msg = args._2();
    if (msg instanceof String) {
        log.info("received msg, queueing: {} ", msg);
        messages = messages.enqueue((String) msg);
        pump();
    }
    return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
}
```

This is a direct translation of the logic that you wanted to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `getStageActor()` before, hence can't provide much help there.  As to code conversion from Scala to Java in general, if requirement allows, package a jar containing the classes of the Scala version for the Java app to use; otherwise consider using a Java decompiler (e.g. cfr, procyon) to decompile your Scala-compiled classes and refine the decompiled Java code as needed.

For example decompiling the following dummy Scala code would help reveal a skeletal Java way of `lazy val` and `pattern matching`:

```
class Foo {
  lazy val self = dummy(bar(_: String))
  def dummy(u: Unit) = 1
  private def bar(x: String): Unit = {
    x match {
      case "blah" => println(s"x = $x")
    }
  }
}
```

As shown in the decompiled code below, `lazy val` is done in Java with the value wrapped inside a `synchronized` block with a `bitmap$0` boolean flag, and `pattern matching` gets converted to `if` and `MatchError` exception:

```
$ java -jar /path/to/decompiler/cfr_0_125.jar Foo.class

private int self;
private volatile boolean bitmap$0;

private int self$lzycompute() {
    Foo foo = this;
    synchronized (foo) {
        if (!this.bitmap$0) {
            new Serializable(this){
                public static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
                private final /* synthetic */ Foo $outer;

                public final void apply(String x$1) {
                    this.$outer.Foo$$bar(x$1);
                }
                {
                    if ($outer == null) {
                        throw null;
                    }
                    this.$outer = $outer;
                }
            };
            this.self = this.dummy(BoxedUnit.UNIT);
            this.bitmap$0 = true;
        }
        return this.self;
    }
}

public int self() {
    return this.bitmap$0 ? this.self : this.self$lzycompute();
}

public int dummy(BoxedUnit u) {
    return 1;
}

public void Foo$$bar(String x) {
    String string = x;
    if ("blah".equals(string)) {
        Predef$.MODULE$.println((Object)new StringContext(
                (Seq)Predef$.MODULE$.wrapRefArray((Object[])new String[]{"x = ", ""})
            ).s((Seq)Predef$.MODULE$.genericWrapArray((Object)new Object[]{x}))
        );
        BoxedUnit boxedUnit = BoxedUnit.UNIT;
        return;
    }
    throw new MatchError((Object)string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this is not what I am looking for. this approache really didn't help me as well. unfortunately if I could not find the answer of this question, it makes me disappointed about akka in java. I could not switch to scala.